# cordova android build failure: processArmv7DebugResources

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building a hybrid app with cordova. The setup has been tested with simple application. Both android and iOS build works fine.

After switching to a more complex application, the following error occurred. I googled and found some suggested solution but none of the worked.

I'm new to this so any suggestion appreciated.

```
:processArmv7DebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 28.659 secs
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /Users/wliang/work/hzoom/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/wliang/work/hzoom/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/wliang/work/hzoom/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/wliang/work/hzoom/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any breakthroughs?

Answer (score 4):

In my case I discovered the error with the follow command:

```
cordova build android -- --gradleArg=--info
```

I have found:

```
Executing task ':processArmv7DebugResources' (up-to-date check took 0.009 secs) due to:
  Input file /Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/armv7/debug/www/libs/long/dist/long.min.js.gz has been added.
Starting process 'command '/Users/astaniscia/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt''. Working directory: /Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android Command: /Users/astaniscia/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/astaniscia/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar -M /Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/armv7/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/armv7/debug -A /Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/armv7/debug -m -J /Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android/build/generated/source/r/armv7/debug -F /Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-armv7-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.navionics.poc -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android/build/intermediates/symbols/armv7/debug --no-version-vectors
Successfully started process 'command '/Users/astaniscia/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt''
      Unable to add '/Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/armv7/debug/www/libs/long/dist/long.min.js.gz': file already in archive (try '-u'?)
ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging '/Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-armv7-debug.ap_'
:processArmv7DebugResources FAILED
:processArmv7DebugResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 16,5,main]) completed. Took 0.312 secs.
```

and this line helped me

```
Unable to add '/Users/astaniscia/Workspace/webapp3.0/webapp3.0/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/armv7/debug/www/libs/long/dist/long.min.js.gz': file already in archive (try '-u'?)
```

for me solve the problem... I removed the gzip and now all work fine!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this is what I found to be the issue.

The bower components folder - which normally defaults to `www/lib/` using cordova - was the culprit in my case.

I had modified one of the bower components, to do that I had to first run `npm install` inside the specific package that I was updating. After doing that there was a `node_modules` folder inside the specific component I was updating i.e. `www/lib/{name_of_component}/node_modules`. Basically this **specific** `node_modules` folder is only used for build tools concerning the specific component, and thus it is not needed once you are done updating it and want to build the whole app. Some of the modules inside that specific component's `node_modules` may conflict with the projects node_modules i.e. `{your_app}/node_modules` - this can cause problems. In my case the conflict was with the `semver` module.

So in my case the solution was to delete that specific `node_modules` folder. After that I could build my app without any issues.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old issue, but I recently came upon the same one and hope my experience might help someone else in the future.

After a solid day of looking around I realized it had to do with my **plugins**. For some reason there was an unused dependency in package.json that wouldn't allow it to build.

In my case, it was Firebase, and after removing it from package.json and the plugins folder I ran

```
cordova platform remove android
```

and

```
cordova platform add android
```

then built it again and all of a sudden it was up and running!

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up because **you have one or several accentuated filenames in your project folder**. In my case, it was an image with the char "ç".

This topic can help rename automatically: https://superuser.com/questions/617517/remove-all-illegal-characters-from-all-filenames-in-a-given-folder

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the `node_modules` folder inside `www` that caused the problem.

The solution is to copy your `www` to another folder and exclude `node_modules` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release
```

Thanks to lohith95

from https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-broken-after-gradle-dependencies-update-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-com-android-ide-common-process-processexception-failed-to-execute-aapt/109982/170

Answer (score 0):

This is might because you use crosswalk,

You can try the following commands:

```
    sudo ionic cordova platform remove android 
    sudo rm -rf ./node_modules
    sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
    sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
    sudo ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0 
    sudo ionic cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release
    sudo ionic cordova build android
```